# electron-updater with provider="bitbucket" not working

Tags: electron, bitbucket, electron-builder, bitbucket-pipelines, electron-updater

We have created app using electron.
These are the versions which we are using,
"electron": "13.1.7",
"electron-builder": "23.2.0"
"electron-updater": "5.3.0"

We want to give update functionality using electron-updater.
Our code is available on bitbucket, so we want to use **provider="bitbucket"**, we have tried everything, but its not working.

We are getting below error, please refer screenshot below-

[image]

This is what we have used in windows publish config:-

```
"publish": [
  {
    "provider": "bitbucket",
    "owner": "//out bitbucker owner name", /// its single word owner name
    "token": "//",
    "username": "//my login username",
    "slug": "//our repo name", /// its single word repo name
    "channel": "latest"
  }
],
```

We have created token as mentioned by official electron.build as mentioned below -

[image]

We have placed updated files in downloads location of repo. For eg:- *https://bitbucket.org/owner_name/repo_name/downloads/*

We tried every possible way to change token like we have tried combination of ownerName:appPassword, appPassword and so on...but still we are getting same issue.

Are steps we have performed above are correct? Do we have missed anything here?
Could anyone help us about what configuration we have to put to make electron-updater working with **bitbucket provider**?